# How can send values when user click the mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can send values when user click the mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener ?

I don't know why I always get same value when user click the google map marker.

this is firebase data

```
"Campsite" : {
    "-MfS3VgBGROs_afkVrjl" : {
      "CamperSiteAddress" : "Charles St & Esplanade W, Triabunna TAS 7190, Australia",
      "CamperSiteID" : "-MfS3VgBGROs_afkVrjl",
      "Counrty" : "Australia",
      "CamperSiteImages" : [
 "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/campingau-6b84d.appspot.com/o/CampSitePhotos%2F1627206575487.null?alt=media&token=bff07bd4-fd17-4099-a0d7-db0418311425", 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/campingau-6b84d.appspot.com/o/CampSitePhotos%2F1627206580478.null?alt=media&token=995bf983-0ee8-4f25-af3f-921aa5b0077c", 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/campingau-6b84d.appspot.com/o/CampSitePhotos%2F1627206584072.null?alt=media&token=137b87a9-f6fb-4f75-9d53-7c3efda8cda4" 
],
      "CamperSiteLatitude" : -42.508695,
      "CamperSiteLongitude" : 147.916617,
      "CamperSiteName" : "Encampment Cove Walk"
    }
```

And this is my code

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Campsite");
        Query query = reference.orderByChild("country").equalTo(country);
        query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                list.clear();
                List<String> mapImage = (List<String>) dataSnapshot.child("CamperSiteImages").getValue();
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Double lat = (Double)map.get("CamperSiteLatitude");
                Double lng = (Double)map.get("CamperSiteLongitude");
                LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                String CampSiteName = (String) map.get("CamperSiteName");
                String CampSitePostID = (String) map.get("CamperSiteID");
                String CampSiteType= (String) map.get("type");
                String CampSiteImage = mapImage.get(0);
                list.add(String.valueOf(newLocation));
                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                    try{
                        //bitmap = Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(CampSiteImage).withBitmap().fitCenter().resize(120,120).asBitmap().get();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLocation).title(CampSiteName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icon)));
                    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),CampSitePostID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
```

Now when I click the marker the title is correct, but I always get same CamperSiteID. How can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a marker it returns a [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/Marker) object which has a field available for the application to associate with the marker - called the `tag` field (accessed using `getTag` and `setTag`).  This tag field can then be retrieved in the `onMarkerClick` callback.

So in your code you could do this:

```
Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLocation).title(CampSiteName).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(icon)));
m.setTag(CampSitePostID);
```

and in the marker click callback:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    String campSiteID = "?";
    if (marker.getTag() != null) {
        campSiteID = (String) marker.getTag();
    }
    //...use campSiteID instead of CampSitePostID
}
```

Here's more info from the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#associate_data_with_a_marker.

If your application has more data to associate than a simple String then more complex solutions can be implemented:

1. Since the `tag` is an object instance you can associate any object of your choosing such as a class with many properties (or even the `map` variable in your example)
2. Since each marker has a unique `id` field (`m.getId()`) you can use that field as a key into your own map implementation to access associated data.  Marker ids are unique for the current instance of the map (the numbering is reset when the app is restarted or the map is reinitialized).
3. As combination of (1) and (2) you can create your own mapping key and set that as the `tag` value and use that key to map into your own data.

---

Notes:

1. The map has only one marker click event handler.  In your code you are setting the marker click event handler on every firebase callback.  This is unnecessary and this leads to the likely result where the last marker added is the CampSitePostId used for *any* marker click.
2. In your `onChildAdded` you first `list.clear()` which empties the list and then perform one `list.add` and then loop on the size of the list; but it will always be of size 1.